# How to create a week counter?

Tags: sql-server

Example of what I am trying to do:

I have 10 employees. They all started on different days throughout the year. Each ***potentially*** gets paid once a week. I want to query their first paycheck and call that week 1 for all employees. Then each subsequent paycheck will be 2...3...through 13. So basically I want to see what each of their first 13 weeks on the job looked like stacked against each other. The catch here is the potentially above. Employees might not get paid each week so I would want to see a zero for that week. I know this is tough because there is no record to read for that week.  I would expect my output to look something like this:

[image]

I was thinking of using a Tally Table of some kind and reading their hire date +7 over an over? I am open to any idea.

Comment: Request you to provide the DDL and sample data in the insert into format also expected output all in the text format. So, it can be consumed and verified with the answer easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Row_Number()` as shown below.

```
SELECT Week
    ,EmployeeId
    ,[Paycheck Date]
    ,Amount
    ,Row_Number() OVER (
        PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY [Paycheck Date]
        ) AS WkNo
FROM Yourtable
```

To create and join with the Week Number table you can try something as shown below.

```
;WITH WeekTable(n) AS
(
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n + 1 FROM WeekTable WHERE n < 52
)
SELECT 
    n 
FROM WeekTable 
left join (SELECT Week
        ,EmployeeId
        ,[Paycheck Date]
        ,Amount
        ,Row_Number() OVER (
            PARTITION BY EmployeeId ORDER BY [Paycheck Date]
            ) AS WkNo
    FROM Yourtable)emp on n = emp.WkNo
ORDER BY n
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 1000);
```